# Are dynamically created classes always "unreachable" for gc in Python?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I have a question regarding garbage collection in Python. After reading some insightful articles on why one might prefer to run a Python program with disabled garbage collection*, I decided to search and remove all circular references in my code to allow objects to be destroyed through ref-counting alone.

For finding existing circular references, I put a call to gc.collect() in the tearDown method of my unittest cases and to print out a warning whenever a value >0 was returned. Most of the issues found were easy fixed by refactoring or the use of weak references.

After a while though, I came across a rather curious problem, best expressed in code:

```
import gc
gc.disable()

def bar():
    class Foo( object ):
        pass

bar()
print( gc.collect() ) # prints 6
```

When removing the call to bar(), gc.collect() returns 0, as expected.

It seems like even though Foo is created within the scope of the function bar and never returned to the outside, it sticks around and causes the garbage collector to find unreachable objects.

When moving Foo outside the scope of bar, everything works fine again. That solution is however not applicable to the problem I am trying to solve in the affected code (dynamic creation of ctypes.Structures for serialization).

The following two approaches did not work either:

```
import gc
gc.disable()

def bar():
    type( "Foo", ( object, ), {} )

bar()
print( gc.collect() ) # prints 6 again
```

or even the very 'clever':

```
import gc
gc.disable()

import weakref

def bar():
    weakref.ref( type( "Foo", ( object, ), {} ) )

bar()
print( gc.collect() ) # still prints 6
```

To top it off, here's an example that actually works ... but only in Python2:

```
import gc
gc.disable()

def bar():
    class Foo(): # not subclassing object
        pass

bar()
print( gc.collect() ) # prints 0 - finally?
```

The code above however, does again print out "6" in Python3 - I suspect, because all user defined classes are new-style classes in Python3.

So, am I stuck with Python2, weird "unreachable objects" in Python3 or do I have to follow up every call to bar with a manual garbage collection?

*(articles on running Python with gc.disable() )

http://pydev.blogspot.de/2014/03/should-python-garbage-collector-be.html
http://dsvensson.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/the-garbage-garbage-collector-of-python/

---

See roippi's answer for why the above does behave as expected.

For future reference though, here's a small workaround that will fix this particular problem. Not saying that disabling gc is the right thing for anyone to do, but if you feel like it's the right thing for you, this is how I did it:

```
import gc
gc.disable()

def requiresGC( func ):
    def func_wrapper( *args, **kwargs ):
        result = func( *args, **kwargs )
        gc.collect()
        return result
    return func_wrapper

@requiresGC
def bar():
    class Foo( object ):
        pass

bar()
print( gc.collect() ) # prints 0
```

Note however, that this decorator will cause significant slowdown, if bar() is a function that is called regularly. In my case however (serialization), this is not the case and having the gc-overhead contained to a few specific functions seems a reasonable compromise.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to answer so quickly! :-)

Comment: You can also use the `weakref` module for references which will not impede garbage collection.

Comment: I recommend just not turning off the GC. It's a part of Python that code is allowed to rely on. The interpreter core creates reference cycles, the standard library creates reference cycles, external libraries create reference cycles, you probably create reference cycles without realizing it, everyone creates reference cycles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring a new-style class - either statically or via `type` - creates a circular reference (actually, more than one).  Here's the clearest example I can provide:

```
class Baz:
    pass

print(Baz in Baz.__mro__)
#True
```

There's a few other circular refs in `Baz`'s `__dict__` too, but one is all you need.

There's not really any workaround I can offer you - this is what the GC is there for, I'm afraid.  I can point you to [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue9417) that's been around for a while if you'd like to dive in further.

Comment: Hearing about running Python with no GC I can't help but remember the fights the Gentoo devs would get into with users wanting to set [crazy global CFLAGS](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) and try to re-compile their whole system. This kind of "optimization" ends up being Pyrrhic because over time you will almost re-invent the gc manually, and eventually you will look at your code and think, "Hmm, it would be nice if this ran automatically..."